# 500 Error in production adapter rails when starting new user session

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, controller, rails-models

I have been having this issue ever since I deployed and i can't figure it out.

I'll give some information and let me know if you need anything else! Thanks!

```
I, [2013-09-08T12:44:31.935143 #19456]  INFO -- : Started POST "/sessions" for {IP ADDRESS} at 2013-09-08 12:44:31 -0700
I, [2013-09-08T12:44:31.937969 #19456]  INFO -- : Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2013-09-08T12:44:31.938102 #19456]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"{AUTHENTICITY TOKEN}", "email"=>"mike@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
I, [2013-09-08T12:44:31.941064 #19456]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
F, [2013-09-08T12:44:31.943631 #19456] FATAL -- : 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

Obviously it's telling me that the "users" table doesn't exist, but that BS, because it does. Perhaps it can't find the table? Which i ALSO think is wierd, because I created the table using Rails migrations.

Here is my production Adapter just for reference:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: {DATABASENAME}
  username: {USERNAME}
  password: {PASSWORD}
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Here is my seeds file:

```
User.create([{ email: 'mike@test2.com' }, { password_digest: 'password' }])
```

And my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

And my sessions controller (handles the login):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

I created the user directly in the database, so the issue isn't that the user doesnt exist, the log file is saying the table 'users' doesnt exist, but that is false as well...i really don't know whats going on...

OH, BTW this all works in development. Login, user creation, everything. I was using sqlite3 for development and switched to mysql for production, just screwed everything up....

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure the tablename is "users" and not "user". Since you have created it manually, this could be the first mistake.

Comment: I created the username and password manually by adding a row to the database. The Database, its tables and columns were generated by rails via the rake db:migrate command

Comment: Then the most probable cause is your environment. It is still using your dev environment and not production. Check in db folder if there are sqlite files.

Comment: Did you run the migrations in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is the fix if anyone else is having an issue with their seeds not working:

This is what I was using:

```
User.create([{ email: 'mike@test2.com' }, { password_digest: 'password' }])
```

This is what it should be:

```
users =User.create!(:email 'mike@test2.com', :password 'password', :password_confirmation 'password')

users.save
```

Using

```
Create!
```

instead of just plain

```
Create
```

enables validation, and the seed will fail and explain the problem. In my case, it was that I was using password_digest, which is the column name, instead of password and password_confirmation.

Also, save the seed creation in a variable (users in my case), then save said variable by doing this:

```
users.save
```

Simple as that!

Hope this helps a fellow newbie in the future!